# Binding to dictionary, create missing entries automatically

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, binding

Binding to dictionary value by entry key is quite simple:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeDictionary[someKey]}" />
```

However the entry must exists:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> SomeDictionary { get; } = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "someKey", "someValue" },
};
```

Otherwise (for e.g. empty dictionary) an exception is thrown:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 17 : Cannot get 'Item[]' value (type 'String') from 'SomeDictionary' (type 'Dictionary~2'). BindingExpression:Path=SomeDictionary[someKey]; DataItem='MainWindow' (Name=''); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String') TargetInvocationException:'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
>      at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)

Is there a way to automatically add entry with default value for specified by binding key instead of exception?

Currently this can be achieved if binding is done in the code:

```
if (!SomeDictionary.ContainsKey("someKey"))
    SomeDictionary.Add("someKey", "defaultValue");
textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding("[someKey]") { Source = SomeDictionary });
```

I am looking for reusable xaml solution.

Things I am thinking about:

- create behavior (attached property) or markup extension to run code similar to that one above;
- catch exception somehow and *rebind* or what else?
- create own `Binding` to do *something*, but what exactly?

Perhaps there is an easier way?

Comment: Have you tried a Converter? that is what i would do.

Comment: and do you want to maintain the "somekey" value when creating a default value?

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround is to wrap dictionary into `DynamicObject`, this will allow to *intercept* binding calling getter/setter:

```
public class Wrapper<T> : DynamicObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    readonly Dictionary<string, T> _dictionary;

    public Wrapper(Dictionary<string, T> dictionary)
    {
        _dictionary = dictionary;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        T value;
        if (!_dictionary.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out value))
        {
            value = default(T);
            _dictionary.Add(binder.Name, value);
        }
        result = value;
        return true;
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        _dictionary[binder.Name] = (T)value;
        OnPropertyChanged(binder.Name);
        return true;
    }

    ...
}
```

and then use it

```
public Wrapper<string> WrapperProperty { get; } = new Wrapper<string>(new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    //{ "someKey", "someValue" }, // no problems if commented
});
```

The binding in xaml become `{Binding WrapperProperty.someKey}`.

Bonus: `INotifyPropertyChanged` (not implemented in code) make dictionary entry observable, allowing to bind multiple element to same *entry*.